# Converting pandas columns to datetime64 including missing values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Working with Pandas to work with some timeseries based data that contains dates, numbers, categories etc.

The problem I'm having is getting pandas to deal with my date/time columns correctly from a DataFrame created from a CSV. There are 18 date columns in my data, they are not continuous and unknown values in the raw CSV have a string value of "Unknown". Some columns have ALL cells with a valid datetime in it and correctly get their dtype guessed by the pandas read_csv method. There are some columns however that in a particular data sample have ALL cells as "Unknown" and these get typed as object.

My code to load the CSV is as follows:

```
self.datecols = ['Claim Date', 'Lock Date', 'Closed Date', 'Service Date', 'Latest_Submission', 'Statement Date 1', 'Statement Date 2', 'Statement Date 3', 'Patient Payment Date 1', 'Patient Payment Date 2', 'Patient Payment Date 3', 'Primary 1 Payment Date', 'Primary 2 Payment Date', 'Primary 3 Payment Date', 'Secondary 1 Payment Date', 'Secondary 2 Payment Date', 'Tertiary Payment Date']
self.csvbear = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col="Claim ID", parse_dates=True, na_values=['Unknown'])
self.csvbear = pd.DataFrame.convert_objects(self.csvbear, convert_dates='coerce')
print self.csvbear.dtypes
print self.csvbear['Tertiary Payment Date'].values
```

The output from print self.csvbear.dtypes

```
Prac                            object
Doctor Name                     object
Practice Name                   object
Specialty                       object
Speciality Code                  int64
Claim Date              datetime64[ns]
Lock Date               datetime64[ns]
Progress Note Locked            object
Aging by Claim Date              int64
Aging by Lock Date               int64
Closed Date             datetime64[ns]
Service Date            datetime64[ns]
Week Number                      int64
Month                   datetime64[ns]
Current Insurance               object
...
Secondary 2 Deductible        float64
Secondary 2 Co Insurance      float64
Secondary 2 Member Balance    float64
Secondary 2 Paid              float64
Secondary 2 Witheld           float64
Secondary 2 Ins                object
Tertiary Payment Date          object
Tertiary Payment ID           float64
Tertiary Allowed              float64
Tertiary Deductible           float64
Tertiary Co Insurance         float64
Tertiary Member Balance       float64
Tertiary Paid                 float64
Tertiary Witheld              float64
Tertiary Ins                  float64
Length: 96, dtype: object
[nan nan nan ..., nan nan nan]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see, the Tertiary Payment Date col should be a datetime64 dtype, but it's simply a object, and the actual content of it is just NaN (put there from the read_csv function for string 'Unknown').

How can I reliably convert all of the date columns to have datetime64 as a dtype and NaT for 'Unknown' cells?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you have an all-nan column it won't be coerced properly by `read_csv`. easiest is just to do this (which if a column is already datetime64[ns] will just pass thru).

```
In [3]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = Timestamp('20130101'), B = np.random.randn(5), C = np.nan))

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
                    A         B   C
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00 -0.859994 NaN
1 2013-01-01 00:00:00 -2.562136 NaN
2 2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.410673 NaN
3 2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.480578 NaN
4 2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.464771 NaN

[5 rows x 3 columns]

In [5]: df.dtypes
Out[5]: 
A    datetime64[ns]
B           float64
C           float64
dtype: object

In [6]: df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])

In [7]: df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
                    A         B   C
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00 -0.859994 NaT
1 2013-01-01 00:00:00 -2.562136 NaT
2 2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.410673 NaT
3 2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.480578 NaT
4 2013-01-01 00:00:00  0.464771 NaT

[5 rows x 3 columns]

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]: 
A    datetime64[ns]
B           float64
C    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

`convert_objects` won't forcibly convert a column to datetime unless it has a least 1 non-nan thing that is a date (that why your example fails). `to_datetime` can be more aggressive because it 'knows' that you really want to convert it.

Comment: fyi, you may need to pass ``coerce=True`` to ``to_datetime`` if you have embedded-non dates (and you want them to converted to ``NaT``

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to need it since the read_csv coerce has made all data for the date cols that isn't a date to NaNs. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 2):

I like your method of using `DataFrame.convert_objects`, much more elegant than what I had tried many eons before.

Looking at the API docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

> parse_dates : boolean, list of ints or names, list of lists, or dict
>
> If True -> try parsing the index. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column. If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as a single date column. {‘foo’ : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’

I presume that you're at the data wrangling stage of your analysis right now. Formatting the data to get it into the right format is generally the longest part of analysis. Some things just don't behave well, so hard-coding those things for special cases is going to be necessary.

Therefore, since you know which columns don't parse properly, I suggest that you go back into the code, and parse those columns right at the `read_csv` stage. Here's a suggestion:

```
self.csvbear = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col="Claim ID", parse_dates=[column, numbers, go, here], na_values=['Unknown'])
```

You will note that `parse_dates=True` has been changed to `parse_dates=[column, numbers, go, here]`. For the columns that aren't behaving properly, this is probably the quickest brute-force way to get to where you need to.