# Subtract two pandas datetime.time columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

This should be simple, but I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using python 2.7.

I've imported an .xlsx to a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

# Open excel file as object
all = pd.ExcelFile('trash prediction.xlsx')
raw = all.parse('Sheet1', skiprows=0, na_values=['NA'])

# Drop rows without time information
raw = raw.drop(raw.index[0:27])

raw.columns = ['date', 'id', 'marketer_prediction', 
               'start', 'steps','truck_is','trash_prediction',
              'total', 'top','mid','bot','problems','finish']

raw.dtypes
```

And the output is

```
    date                   datetime64[ns]
id                             object
marketer_prediction            object
start                          object
steps                         float64
truck_is                       object
trash_prediction               object
total                         float64
top                           float64
mid                           float64
bot                           float64
problems                       object
finish                         object
dtype: object
```

I'd like to subtract raw.finish from raw.start, they are times in the excel sheet, but here in the dataframe both of them are labeled as objects.

```
raw.finish-raw.start
```

Gives the error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'"

Why does dtype say that raw.finish and raw.start are objects, while when I subtract them they are labeled datetime.time?  Is there another way to reveal that a column is datetime.time?

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689288/converting-pandas-columns-to-datetime64-including-missing-values) uses pd.to_datetime to convert columns to  datetime64[ns], but when I try the following

```
raw['start'] = pd.to_datetime(raw['start'])
```

I get the error: "TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()"

What format should the times be in to subtract them, and how do I convert them to that format?

Comment: are you sure all the observations in finish and start have the same type? This might explain why you get as column type 'object'

Comment: That's a great point. How do I check for the type in a single column?

Comment: You can do the following to get all the different types that appear in the column:

set(map(type, raw.finish.values.tolist()))

Comment: Great that's very helpful. The output is `{datetime.time, float}` - so there's at least one offending float value in there. How can I find out which value it is?

Comment: You can use boolean mask as usual:

raw.finish[[isinstance(el, float) for el in raw.finish]]

Comment: Shoot. I removed the row with float but it's still not working.  I can't subtract the datetime.time columns from each other and I can't convert them to datetime64[ns], I still get the same errors.

Comment: After your finding about the mixed types, I guess it is worth to rephrase the question, possibly providing a minimal reproducible example.
In this way somebody can give you a proper answer (or you might find the answer yourself while working on the reproducible example)